# Programmatically change the width/height of ColorBox onClick

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the jquery plugin [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

I have a page with several item listings.  Each listing has a ColorBox attached to it.

```
$("a.modalButton").each(function(){
    $(this).colorbox({
        width:"933px", 
        height:"720px", 
        iframe:true, 
        onComplete:function(){ 
            //remove the text from the close button
            //wasn't sure how else to do that
            $('#cboxClose').html('');
            }
    });
});
```

In each ColorBox window there is an "email me" button.  When it is clicked I replace the html content that is in the window with a form to email the listing.

**I would like the window to resize to fit the form after this button is clicked**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$('.email_me_class').click(function() {
  $.colorbox.resize() 
})
```

just throwing it out there, never used this plugin before.